# Securely connect to External DB via Java Desktop Application (External DB Credentials)

Tags: database, security, connection, client-server

after hours of searching around, I just couldn't find a complete answer to my question.
My question is: How can a Desktop Application (I'm using Java but this is global question) connect to an External DB securely and that means, without
1) hard-coding the DB credentials or
2) storing them in a file (encrypted or not) or
3) calling a server function to establish a connection

A possible answer would be encrypting the actual code files (?) to avoid de-compilation in the case of hard-coding the DB credentials - and I dont know if thats still secure...

Example of such application to better explain myself:
User accesses the application (Possible user authentication with LOCAL Application DB but that's irrelevant) then through the application access the Web Server and Web DB with all standard actions like select/update/delete through given menu options. How can we establish a secure connection without revealing any credentials used?

Answer (score 0):

Only by using Kerberos or some other distributed authentication mechanism, such that the server trusts the client machine to authenticate..

Comment: Well yeah, although I dont know much about Kerberos (read some at Wiki), that is actually saying to the WebServer to trust the actual Client that tries to connect. But what if that actual Client is malicious and although he can get identified with the WebServer, he may also have a maliciously modified application that the WebServer may or not detect...